# Should we generate OAuth2 Credential web_client_id for development?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

i'm trying to develop an android application that connected to google-cloud-endpoints, but still use development server, i use **android studio** to emulate the endpoints server.

the question is: since our development server is on our local address, should we generate an OAuth2 Credentials Client ID for http://192.168.0.100 address?

at this moment our android application still cannot auth to our emulated endpoint server, it shows an exception:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:286)
```

the other error that i found at logcat:

```
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is it on port 80 or a higher one? Is the address accessible to the network the test device is on?

Comment: we use port 8080 for development server by default, yes it accessible from test device, we can open the endpoints sample screen using chrome at test device, we use this url to access the API from android client: http://192.168.0.100:8080/_ah/api/

Comment: So you should "generate an OAuth2 Credentials Client ID" but use http://192.168.0.100:8080 instead of http://192.168.0.100

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try to put the address http://192.168.0.100 in the "Redirect URIs and in Javascript Origins" @ https://console.developers.google.com/project/**project-id**/apiui/credential, and again download the client_secrets.json file and replace it with the old json file and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, i create the Android Client ID with my production certificate, in android studio it create it's own certificate for debug...

it produce different SHA1...

Thank you all...